# Убирание заднего фона с аватарки

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-api, pillow

Хочу создать команду, которая сжигает аватарку пользователя. Ну, конечно эту шуточну. Но! Когда я тестирую, у меня черный фон. Можно ли это как-то убрать?

Вот кусочек кода:

```
@commands.command(aliases=['сжигать', 'fire'])
    async def сжечь(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        if member == None:
            member = ctx.author
        
        embed=discord.Embed(title=':tools: Подождите! Нам надо сгенерировать изображение...', description='Это может занять не больше 2-х минут...', color=random.choice(colors))
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
        
        fire = Image.open('fire.jpg')
        asset = member.avatar_url_as(size=128)

        data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
        profilepic = Image.open(data)

        profilepic = profilepic.resize((323, 323))

        fire.paste(profilepic, (274, 253))

        fire.save('firepic.jpg')

        await msg.delete()
        await ctx.send(file= discord.File('firepic.jpg'))

        os.remove('firepic.jpg')
```

А так-же картинка, которая получается: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно просто удалить фон аватарки, как вариант использовать [api](https://www.remove.bg/ru/api#rate-limit) от [remove.bg](https://remove.bg)

Как по мне, бэк удаляет неплохо, так что можно использовать, так же посмотрите рейт лимиты.